# Copy Rows to different sheets, IF cell value matches to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets. sheet1 is monthly Value on col A. Sheet 2 is daily value on col A, I would Like Excel to look for the same value in worksheet 2 (Daily), then once it finds that exact value, to copy the matched rows form sheet 1 (monthly) and paste it in sheet 2 (Daily).
Any ideas how to write a VBA code that will automate this copy and paste values process? (see the **screenshot**)
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5LqW.png
    [on the right handside, data is per month (last day of each month), i need to match col Aof both sheets, and bring the data to other sheet on exact day (last day of that month)][1]

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages.

Comment: @iLuvLogix , thanks, i added a screen shot, it might help

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
Sub Copy18()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsD2 As worksheet, wsM2 As Worksheets
Dim LastRow As long, LastCol As Long, i as long
Dim Cell As Range, Rng As Range, SearchR As Range, CopyRng As Range, PasteRng As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsD2 = wb.Sheets("Daily-2")
Set wsM2 = wb.Sheets("Monhly-2")

LastCol = wsM2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = wsM2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = wsD2.Range(wsD2.Cells(1,1), wsD2.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

For Each Cell in Rng
    Set SearchR = wsM2.Range("A:A").Find(Cell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not SearchR Is Nothing Then
        i = LastCol = wsM2.Cells(SearchR.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set CopyRng = wsM2.Range(wsM2.Cells(SearchR.Row, 1), wsM2.Cells(SearchR.Row, i))
        Set PasteRng = wsD2.Range(wsD2.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1), wsD2.Cells(LastRow + 1, i))
        PasteRng.Value = CopyRng.Value
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```